# Aid in understanding of how to interpet certain xml coding

Tags: xml, if-statement

Can someone please explane the following code. I used to code FSX Gauge XML but it's been a long time. I no longer understand. Especially what values are being set by S0 and S1 (is it 0 and 1)?
Also, what does "l0 0 > if{" and "l1 l0 != if{" mean?

```
<UPDATE_CODE>
    (L:FSUIPC_C510_Ignition_2, Number) s0
    (A:TURB ENG IGNITION SWITCH EX1:2, Number) s1
    l0 0 &gt; if{
        l1 l0 != if{
                0 (&gt;L:FSUIPC_C510_Ignition_2)
                1 (&gt;B:ENGINE_Ignition_2_Toggle) 
            }       
        }
</UPDATE_CODE>
```

Looked for XML tutorials on the internet. Either found generic explanations or couldn't find if, then, else discussions.

Comment: I would guess, l0 greater than 0, and l1 does not equal l0 respectively.